# I installed ImageMagick and now nvidia-smi cannot communicate with nvidia drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, imagemagick

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS and was using a Nvidia GPU just fine yesterday. I then installed imagemagick (only new install although this may include dependencies), restarted my PC, and now I am unable to use my GPU. Nvidia-smi command returns

```
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

Anyone know what setting ImageMagick may have automatically changed on install to cause this issue?

EDIT: `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` shows the following line: `(II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Deleting GPU-0`

EDIT 2: List of packages installed by imagemagick:

- imagemagick-6.q16:amd64
- imagemagick:amd64
- libilmbase24:amd64
- libopenexr24:amd64
- libmagickcore-6.q16-6-extra:amd64
- libnetpbm10:amd64
- netpbm:amd64
- linux-modules-5.13.0-25-generic:amd64
- linux-image-5.13.0-25-generic:amd64
- linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-25-generic:amd64
- linux-hwe-5.13-headers-5.13.0-25:all
- linux-headers-5.13.0-25-generic:amd64

EDIT 3:

```
$ dkms status
nvidia, 460.73.01, 5.11.0-46-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 460.73.01, 5.8.0-53-generic, x86_64: installed

$ uname -r
5.13.0-27-generic
```

Comment: Why did you install ImageMagick? It comes installed on Ubuntu desktop systems by default.

Comment: Check to make sure that Secure Boot is disabled in your BIOS.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I needed the convert command and apt said I needed to install imagemagick

Comment: @heynnema secure boot is disabled in BIOS (checked today after the issues). Although, yes, I needed to do that to originally get the GPU to work

Comment: Edit your question and show me `dkms status` and `uname -r`.

Comment: @heynnema edited the question. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on `dkms status` and `uname -r` information, you need to reinstall your Nvidia drivers.

Open `Software & Updates`, select the "Additional Drivers" tab, and note what drivers are available for your configuration.

Select the Nvidia driver that indicates "proprietary, tested", probably version 470. Do not select the 495 driver.

Reboot when complete. Recheck the `nvidia-smi` command output.

Comment: Thanks for the help, nvidia-smi shows my gpu. However, the command `dkms` no longer exists. Do you have any idea what the issue was? Was it that the kernel was updated and the 460 drivers don't work with the 5.13 kernel?

Comment: @SvenVoigt The correct command would be `dkms status`. The issue was that your kernel got upgraded, and the Nvidia dkms driver didn't get rebuilt for the newer kernel for some reason. Did you install the Nvidia version 470?

Comment: Yes, I installed Nvidia driver version 470. Oh and I see, they needed to be rebuilt. Thanks! When I try to run `dkms status` I get the error message `Command 'dkms' not found, but can be installed with: sudo apt install dkms`. Maybe it was only installed for driver version 460

Comment: @SvenVoigt `dkms` must be there for Nvidia to work. Go ahead and reinstall it and then try `dkms status` again... show me that output.

Comment: `dkms status` outputs nothing. Just runs and finishes running the command

Comment: @SvenVoigt That's strange. Show me `ls -al ls /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/updates/dkms` and `ls -al /usr/src`.

Comment: The updates folder doesn't exist in `/lib/modules/5.13.0-27-generic/`. `usr/src` has `linux-headers-5.13.0-25-generic  linux-hwe-5.13-headers-5.13.0-25  nvidia-470.86
linux-headers-5.13.0-27-generic  linux-hwe-5.13-headers-5.13.0-27` folders

Comment: @SvenVoigt Very strange! I don't know how Nvidia is working then. It properly shows the Nvidia source code in /usr/src. Show me `ls -al /var/lib/dkms` and `grep -i dkms /var/log/dpkg.log*`.